# how to install vue addon with same vue instance as main app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, rollupjs

Vue component created with [vue-sfc-rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sfc-rollup) have this part of instalation code that I can't reach.

```js
// To auto-install on non-es builds, when vue is found
// eslint-disable-next-line no-redeclare
/* global window, global */
if ('false' === process.env.ES_BUILD) {
  let GlobalVue = null;
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = window.Vue;
  } else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    GlobalVue = (global as any).Vue;
  }
  if (GlobalVue) {
    // ***********
    //
    // NEVER REACH
    //
    // ***********
    (GlobalVue as typeof _Vue).use(plugin);
  }
}
```

I tried this

```js
const global: any = window
global.Vue = Vue
```

or this

```js
const global: any = window

const vm = new Vue({
  render: (h): VNode => h(Dev),
}).$mount('#app');

global.Vue = vm
```

but global vue **is not available** at the moment the plugin is installed

I ask because if I use Class Component in the addon

```js
@Component
export default class TheComponent extends Vue {
```

Then I receive this warnings in main app:

> vue.runtime.esm.js
>   [Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.
>   [Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly.

I think it's because the component is installed on a different instance of the vue.

EDIT:
of course I install the plugin this way

```
Vue.use(TheComponent)
```

Comment: Can you not just use `Vue.use(plugin)`?

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that's exactly what I'm doing

Comment: I think this is a two Vues situation indeed. So you have to figure out where the Vue instances are coming from. What type of project are you importing the vue-sfc component into?